# Data from textbox to datagrid which is databound

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net-2010

See this image:

[image]

I want to add marked data in datagrid when user press enter after entering quantity. datagrid is data bounded:

I tried below code

```
public bsData As New BindingSource

Dim dtr As New DataTable

   
    dtr.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "hiddenid", .DataType = GetType(Integer),
                     .AutoIncrement = False, .AutoIncrementSeed = False})
    dtr.Columns("hiddenid").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden


    dtr.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "autonumber", .DataType = GetType(String)})
    dtr.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "location", .DataType = GetType(String)})
    dtr.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "date", .DataType = GetType(String)})


1      bsData.DataSource = dtr
 

 2     NDRDataGridView.DataSource = bsData



If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Return) Then

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HiddenidTextBox.Text) Then
            CType(bsData.DataSource, DataTable).Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, AutonumberTextBox1.Text, LocationTextBox.Text, DateTextBox1.Text})
            bsData.MoveLast()
        End If

    End If
```

This code work fine if I use it with one table; like if I use it with textbox and press enter then it will add values of textboxes to datagrid

But when I use it with relationship tables, it hide data of FK table but if I remove LINE 1 AND LINE 2 (mentioned in codes), then I can able to see the FK data.

Comment: This isn't a question. You have posted an image and a software requirement. Hint....look at the keypress event of the textbox. Hint #2, using a textbox to capture numeric data is probably the wrong component, something like a spin edit to prevent bad data is likely more appropriate.

Comment: The question is way too broad. No specific code part presented. We can only assume what's behind that screen. You need to go into more detail about the implementation and ask a more specific question, pointing to the difficulty you're facing, in the code itself.

Comment: please check my codes and reply

Comment: This can be put on hold as "needs details or clarity".